# Binary tree, print only one level (BFS)

Tags: tree, traversal

I'd like to know how could i do to print only a certain level of a binary tree. I've read many questions here about BFS but found none about printin just one level.

How should i change a common BFS search to print, lets say, only level 2 of this tree:

```
   6
  / \
 4   8
/ \ / \
1 5 7  9
```

Leve 2 would be 1, 5, 7, 9. Thank you!

Comment: Track what level you're currently on; and terminate when it gets to 2.

Comment: That is pretty obvious, but i couldn't find the way to do it using regular BFS. It processes the queue with the nodes but doesn't distinguish between levels. It just enqueues and processes them in BFS order.
All i come with is some weird solution checking the amounts of nodes every level should have but it collapses when i think of a non-full tree

Comment: One approach would be to enqueue a tuple of {level,node} rather than just {node}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the answer from a professor for a similar problem.

In a binary search tree, find the lowest number on a certain level
(GenericTree and GenericQueue are specific classes of the course. Also i traslated the whole exercise so some things may sound weird or not :P

```
public int calculateMinimum( BinaryTree<Integer> tree, int n ){
    GenericQueue<BinaryTree<Integer>> queue = new GenericQueue<BinaryTree<Integer>>();
    queue.push(tree);
    queue.push(new BinaryTree<Integer>(-1));
    int nActual = 0; //actual level
    while (!queue.isEmpty()){
        tree = queue.pop();
        if (nActual == n){
            int min = tree.getRootData();
            while (!queue.isEmpty()){
                tree = queue.pop();
                if (!tree.getRootData().equals(-1) && (tree.getRootData()<min))
                    min = tre.getRootData();
            }
            return min;
        }
        if (!tree.getLeftChild().getRootData() == null))
            queue.push(tree.getLeftChild());
        if (!tree.getRightChild().getRootData() == null))
            queue.push(tree.getRightChild());
        if ((tree.getRootData().equals(-1) && (!queue.isEmpty())){
            nActual++;
            queue.push(new BinaryTree<Integer>(-1));
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a level property on your Node. And then when you traverse on the tree, you ask:

```
if (level == 2) //or whatever level you wish
{
    ...
}
```

Here is a good example: [Find all nodes in a binary tree on a specific level (Interview Query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349853/find-all-nodes-in-a-binary-tree-on-a-specific-level-interview-query)

If there is no level on the Node and you can't change it, then you can make it as a global variable in the method you make the checks - not preferable but one more solution. I haven't check this answer in code, but I believe it should be very close to the solution.

e.g:

```
int level = 0;

     public void PrintOneLevelBFS(int levelToPrint)    
     {      
        Queue q = new Queue();
        q.Enqueue(root); //Get the root of the tree to the queue.

        while (q.count > 0)
        {
            level++; //Each iteration goes deeper - maybe the wrong place to add it (but somewhere where the BFS goes left or right - then add one level).
            Node node = q.DeQueue();

            if (level == levelToPrint)
            {
                ConsoleWriteLine(node.Value) //Only write the value when you dequeue it
            }

            if (node.left !=null)
            {
                q.EnQueue(node.left); //enqueue the left child
            }
            if (n.right !=null)
            {
                q.EnQueue(node.right); //enqueue the right child
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you Misha, that is a good solution, but what if you couldn't have that property on the nodes?
I'm on computer science university and i think this could be a possible test exercise.

Comment: Mm i don't think it will work.It will increase the level each time the loop runs ( 1 loop = 1 node, then, not for each level).

Comment: Yes, that's why you should think to put the level on the right place, moreover, if you maintains the same level than you shoudln't add it, maybe you can make one more check before making level++